# Fetch JSON object into jQuery ajax with given URL and key

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

An API at remote server would return a HTTP 200 response with JSON of All Contacts available with key "contacts"

```
"contacts" : [{
    "id" : "1"
    "contact_name" : "Bob"
    "contact_phone" : "9876543210",
    "contact_email" : "bob@example.com"
}]
```

The API supports Cross Domain requests using CORS and works on vanilla Ajax Requests (No need to implement JSONP Callbacks). 
My code so far;

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url:  'http://ui-proj.practodev.in/contacts',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                $("#contacts").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
<div id="contacts"></div>
```

But I'm unable to get JSON data in my page. Please suggest me where i may wrong.

Comment: Is the success callback being called? do you have a div for contacts?

Comment: If you check the console, you'll see you're getting a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response from your request. http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/w92Lv/. You'll need to check the API and see if you need to pass some form of credentials in the request.

Comment: I have a <div> tag with id name contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Using Fiddler to see the response of that request I've got that you are missing an authorization header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 UNAUTHORIZED
Server: nginx/1.4.1
Date: Sat, 02 Nov 2013 13:44:39 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 43
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-USER

{
  "X-USER": "Missing X-USER in headers"
}
```

You can check how to add headers in http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I got an instruction from API that, "While accessing any of the urls from Contacts Demo API, pass a header parameter X-USER with value as your email address to autheticate."
So i added like headers: {'X-USER' : 'bob@example.com'} is that ok ?

Comment: The only way to know it is testing :)

Comment: I am a beggineer in front end and not so much familier with jQuery and ajax. Will you please help me how to test javascript code with firebug ?

Comment: Normally I use Chrome, there is an excellent course to learn how to use the Chrome DevTools that are similar to Firebug: http://discover-devtools.codeschool.com/ .  And if you are using web services you should learn fiddler or a similar tools to simulate http request